# iOS documentation for delegates in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, documentation

How should we document delegates in Swift? If I put my documentation in the protocol the class will seem empty (documentation wise) and wise versa. And if I put it both places it will be a hassle to maintain.

Is there some way to link the method in our classes to the documented protocol methods?

An example of code documentation for a protoctol:

```
protocol SomeDelegate: class {
  /**
   Awesome method
   - parameters:
     - oneParam: This works great
  */
  func testAwesome(oneParam: Int)


}
```

In my class:

```
class AwesomeClass: SomeDelegate {
  /// Should we just make a little note? Or what does apple expect?
  func testAwesome(oneParam: Int) {
    // implement stuff
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Example of SeeAlso:

```
/// - Note: Implementation of Something, (note this works)
/// - SeeAlso: Test (note this does not show when holding alt)
func doneWithSomething() {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main explanation should be on the protocol class in order to developers who will implemenet your delegate knows what the are going to implement.

In you class file add a little explanation about method and use the **SeeAlso** tag in your comment naming the protocol class

```
class AwesomeClass: SomeDelegate {
  /*
      Should we just make a little note? Or what does apple expect?

       - SeeAlso: `SomeDelegate` 
  */
  func testAwesome(oneParam: Int) {
    // implement stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't get seealso to work, both with lower case and first word uppercase it doesn't work. But Note works so I could use that instead... But I think this would be the right approach.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't wok"? SeeAlso content It's not an hyperlink, it's plain text. If you want to know more about Swift documentation take a look at this [article](http://ericasadun.com/2015/06/14/swift-header-documentation-in-xcode-7/)

Comment: I mean when I hold alt (options) down and click on it, the text in that block doesn't appear. For some reason that tag is ignored. I'm using Swift 2.3 so I don't know if it is related to that?

Comment: SeeAlso documentation tag is supported since prior versions of Swift. I see that you're using Xcode 8 (beta). Could you post the block comment?